# How do I use react-pdf in a vite project?

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-pdf

My goal is to use react-pdf from https://react-pdf.org/ in a newly created vite project.
I have dowloaded peact-pdf with npm package manager and followed the basic getting started set-up from react-pdf. The problem is that the components from react-pdf will not render. I am getting the error messages displayed below.

[These are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpky4.png)

Here is the code from app.tsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import { PDFViewer } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#E4E4E4",
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

// Create Document Component
const MyDocument = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #2</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src="/vite.svg" className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://reactjs.org" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Vite + React</h1>
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>
          count is {count}
        </button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
      <div>
        <PDFViewer>
          <MyDocument />
        </PDFViewer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`your text`

I tried loading the  in another react project without vite and it worked. However it does not work with vite.

Comment: Please paste the error in the question, otherwise no one else with the same problem as you will find it.

Comment: This solved my problem using vite + react + TS and react-pdf.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74251862/20588754

Answer (score 0):

npm i events

In my case it worked
I hope I helped you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't work for me!