# Can't generate pdf download link with react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I'm new with react. I want to create a website that can generate pdf file to download. I use React with Vite and Tailwind. I found this in internet: https://react-pdf.org/advanced#on-the-fly-rendering.

I try it in my code but nothing shows up.

```
import {Document, Page, PDFDownloadLink, StyleSheet, Text, View} from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import React from "react";

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#E4E4E4",
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

// Create Document Component
const MyDoc = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #2</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
const Dashboard = () => (
  <div>
    <PDFDownloadLink
      className=" bg-slate-600"
      document={<MyDoc />}
      fileName="somename.pdf"
    >
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
          <button className=" bg-slate-500">Loading document...</button>
        ) : (
          <button className=" bg-slate-500">Download now!</button>
        )
      }
    </PDFDownloadLink>
  </div>
);
export default Dashboard;
```

And i call this from my App.jsx file

```
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className=" bg-slate-500">
      <Dashboard />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[This is how it's look when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM0HD.png)

[This is when i inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqRvU.png)

I run it from brave browser, but it still the same when i run it from google browser.
Anyone know why this is happen? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't think browser can be the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React PDF + Vite implementation Error: Uncaught SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620099/react-pdf-vite-implementation-error-uncaught-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of searching, i found that my problem is caused by vite.  [This post pretty much solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620099/react-pdf-vite-implementation-error-uncaught-syntaxerror)