# Cannot access "util.inspect" in client code. Sass Error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, nuxtjs3

Any ideas about this error? I have started experiancing this after `npm upgrade`. It is probably related to https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9238

```json
"nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.10",
"node-sass": "^7.0.1",
"sass": "^1.54.5",
"sass-loader": "^10.2.1"
```

```
Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.inspect" in client code.
get @ browser-external:util:9
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'custom')
    at Object.JSClassExtension_setCustomInspect (sass.dart.js:21478:51)
    at valueClass_closure.call$0 (sass.dart.js:98709:9)
    at sass.dart.js:101365:85
    at holder.<computed> [as $get$valueClass] (sass.dart.js:258:21)
    at Object.main (sass.dart.js:21099:37)
    at main1 (sass.dart.js:21819:9)
    at sass.dart.js:101473:7
    at sass.dart.js:101456:7
    at dartProgram (sass.dart.js:101467:3)
    at exports.load (sass.dart.js:101475:1)
```

Comment: As [mentioned here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9238#issuecomment-1195205461), maybe try to give a try to another package manager. Or give a try to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666018/8816585). Otherwise, why are you even using `node-sass` and `sass` at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Webstorm has autoimported `import {Exception} from "sass";` without my knowleadge into frontend component and browser tried to load sass module which caused the error.

Comment: Oh wow. I was going crazy trying to figure out what the issue was, in my case it did import { types } from 'sass';