# 'fileURLToPath' is not exported by __vite-browser-external

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, rollupjs, nuxtjs3

I'm getting this build error with Nuxt3.0 stable.

`nuxi dev` works fine.

I get the following error when I run `nuxi build`.

```
 ERROR  'fileURLToPath' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/local-pkg/dist/shared.mjs                                                                                     13:57:26
file: /node_modules/local-pkg/dist/shared.mjs:41:9
39: import path from "path";
40: import fs, { promises as fsPromises } from "fs";
41: import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
             ^
42: 
43: // node_modules/.pnpm/yocto-queue@1.0.0/node_modules/yocto-queue/index.js


 ERROR  'fileURLToPath' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/local-pkg/dist/shared.mjs                                                                                     13:57:26

  at error (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)
  at Module.error (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12429:16)
  at Module.traceVariable (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12788:29)
  at ModuleScope.findVariable (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:11440:39)
```

This is my `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
  runtimeConfig: {
  },
  hooks: {
    'components:dirs'(dirs: any) {
      dirs.push({
        path: '~/components',
      })
    },
  },
  components: {
    global: true,
  },
  nitro: {
    preset: 'aws-lambda',
    serveStatic: true,
  },
  app: {
    baseURL: '/',
  },
  build: {
    transpile: ['chart.js'],
  },
  typescript: {
    shim: false,
    strict: true,
  },
  vite: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I tried these but build still doesn't work.

[Polyfill node os module with vite/rollup.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286329/polyfill-node-os-module-with-vite-rollup-js/70666018#70666018)

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/9639#issuecomment-1315152038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get to the root cause per se, but in my case something about my test was causing that issue to happen. Because of that I realized that my tests were being included in the build and I created a `.nuxtignore` file with contents

```
**/*.test.*
```

to make sure tests are not compiled in and that solved the issue for me
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-ignore/

(there are some other answers that talk about using a pollyfil - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666018/35505)