# How can I exclude the https package when using vite?

Tags: vue.js, configuration, vite, cesiumjs

The issue is trivial to reproduce with a default project:

```
yarn create vite my-vue-app --template vue
cd my-vue-app
yarn add cesium vite-plugin-cesium vite -D
```

Updating `vite.config.js` to:

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import cesium from 'vite-plugin-cesium'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), cesium()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    }
  }
})
```

In HelloWorld.vue, import cesium with `import * as Cesium from 'cesium'`

Then, running `yarn dev`, the following error is generated:

```
✘ [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "https". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle]

    node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1373:21:
      1373 │         let result = await callback({
           ╵                      ^

    at packageEntryFailure (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28725:11)
    at resolvePackageEntry (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28722:5)
    at tryNodeResolve (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28453:20)
    at Context.resolveId (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28212:28)
    at Object.resolveId (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44276:64)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:65922:21
    at async file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:39976:34
    at async requestCallbacks.on-resolve (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1373:22)
    at async handleRequest (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:729:13)


  This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

    node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1292:20:
      1292 │       let promise = setup({
           ╵                     ^

    at setup (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:39956:19)
    at handlePlugins (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1292:21)
    at buildOrContextImpl (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:978:5)
    at Object.buildOrContext (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:786:5)
    at /home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2186:68
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.context (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2186:27)
    at Object.context (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2026:58)
    at prepareEsbuildOptimizerRun (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:46041:35)

  The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" was triggered by this import

    node_modules/@cesium/engine/Source/Core/Resource.js:2076:48:
      2076 │       return URL.protocol === "https:" ? import("https") : import("http");
           ╵                                                 ~~~~~~~
```

What is strange about this is that the `https` package does not exist in a browser environment where this is running. Why is it being referenced?

I believe it should be possible to remove references to it by marking the package as "external" (along with other similar packages like http, url, and zlib). However, I am not certain how to do that using vite.

Two things that were tried was to add:

```
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        external: ['https', 'http', 'url', 'zlib']
    }
  },
```

or

```
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['https'],
  },
```

to vite.config.js, but the behavior remained the same.

How can I configure the default project so the https package is not referenced?

Comment: Looks like the package's fault. Considering that esbuild is in use, it makes sense why rollup options alone won't work, probably something like this would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286329/polyfill-node-os-module-with-vite-rollup-js

Comment: Curious...can you reproduce the problem? I have several reports that it is not easily reproducible outside of my machine...